# What's the difference between listview and table layout?

Tags: android

In Android Development page I found that listview is a viewgroup that lists items and table is also a viewgroup that lists views. It seems that they're all forming a "List-like" things?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A ListView is a collection of layouts that are automatically displayed one below the other. The developer adds new items through a piece of code in the Activity. An example is the address book where you have lots of contacts one after the other.

A TableView on the other hand is defined in the layout file and does not only need to contain elements below or above each other but can also arrange elements on the left or on the right. A TableView is exactly what it says: A table with rows and columns

Comment: it would be interesting to know about **GridView** here too :)

Comment: GridView is a ViewGroup that displays items in a two-dimensional, scrollable grid.
Basic difference b/w gridview and tableView is that in grid view only Views that can be displayed in current screen are printed but tableView process all Views so if our data has to be printed in more than one screens using gridView will be more efficient

Comment: Technically all of them are **ViewGroup** but their *purpose-to-serve* are different. Anyhow +1 for the efforts :)